# Phonegap Android - FB like button - I can't

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, button

I need help guys!

In this moment, I developing an app where show my published images on my facebook wall, and need add a "like" button into my app for each image...

I'm using Eclipse with Phonegap and c&p in my project de follow code generated by "developers.facebook .../plugins/like/"

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/QueBajeDios" 
data-send="false" 
data-layout="button_count" 
data-width="450" 
data-show-faces="false">
</div>
```

I choose plugin code for HTML and IFRAME and nothing works...

I tried all version of Phonegap 1.9, 2.4, 2.6... but don't works...

Who can help me? i looking for some help on google on other related post but no solution for me...
and the questions or replys founded are many old...

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I used the iframe approach and did a little change on the url that the plug in gives.

Originally facebook returns this site when you ask for the iframe code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/...></iframe>
```

but from my part since I am doing an app using local resources instead of a server, when that url is called it send to as page header your localhost address.  something like

```
file://path/to/your/app/facebook.com/plugin
```

I just modified the url so it calls facebook directly

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/...></iframe>
```

and like twitter follow button it opens the device browser directly to the facebook/twitter page